# Vue Js - removing spaces from string

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, frontend, trim

```
Let category = "Baby Dress"
```

> I want it to be trimed by spaces and text into lowercase. the output
> as "babydress". I used the following code. but it returns "baby
> dress".

```
category.trim(" ").toLowerCase()
```

I need to understand why it is not doing as I expected and what are the ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working as expected because .trim function is used to remove whitespace from both sides of the string, not from in-between.

[image]

You can use

```
category.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("")
```

Here I'm making the letters lower case, splitting them and then joining them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```js
category.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase()
```

Comment: That will only remove the first space.

Comment: and \s+ is more efficient

Comment: thats true :) in case there were more than one space between words

Answer (score 1):

The trim method only removes spaces at the beginning of the string. What you need is replacing the spaces with nothing with the replace method using regex:

```
category.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Regex is typically slower than the `split` function.

Comment: pretty sure for what he needs the difference is going to be astronomically small :)